# How to reference layout with two onClickListeners in different classes

Tags: java, android, xml, methods, onclicklistener

My question is in reference to the OnclickListner and java classes. I have an xml layout with two buttons; one (when clicked) triggers the "date" class, the other triggers the "email" class. The Email button is working fine, however when I try to set an on click listener to the "date" button, the app crashes(When Triggered). My goal is to be able to click the date button, display the datepicker. Here is my code.
Hopefully this is enough information for anyone to assist me, Thanks everyone.

XML:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:weightSum="100"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@color/white">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/bgklogo3" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Schedule Service"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<ScrollView
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:layout_weight="30" >



    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:text="Your Information"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/firstName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLength="20"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:imeActionLabel="Next"
            android:hint="Enter First Name..." >


        </EditText>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/lastName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:imeActionLabel="Next"
            android:hint="Enter Last Name..." />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/Email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:imeActionLabel="Next"
            android:hint="Enter Email..."
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/PhoneNumber"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:imeActionLabel="Next"
            android:hint="Enter Phone Number..."
            android:inputType="phone" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:text="Vehicle Information"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
       <!--      
         <EditText
             android:id="@+id/tYear"
             android:layout_width="155dp"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:singleLine="true"
            android:imeActionLabel="Next"
             android:hint="What year is it?"/>

         <EditText 
             android:id="@+id/tMake"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:singleLine="true"
            android:imeActionLabel="Next"
             android:hint="What make is it?"/>

         --> 


            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/sYear"
                android:layout_width="155dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:entries="@array/entries"
                android:prompt="@string/prompt" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/sMake"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:entries="@array/entries2"
                android:prompt="@string/prompt2" >
            </Spinner>


        </LinearLayout> 

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/Model"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:imeActionLabel="Next"
            android:hint="Enter Model..." />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:hint="Service Information"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />



        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="30" >

          <!--    <EditText
                android:id="@+id/tpickDate"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:imeActionLabel="Next"
                android:hint="Enter service date..."/>
       -->


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/pickDate"
                android:layout_width="142dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Service Date: "
                android:onClick="onClick"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/dateDisplay"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:text="@+id/dateDisplay"
                android:textSize="20sp" />
                -->
        </LinearLayout>
      <!--   
        <EditText 
            android:id="@+id/tTime"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:imeActionLabel="Next"
            android:hint="Enter service time..." />

        <EditText 
            android:id="@+id/tNeeded"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:imeActionLabel="Next"
            android:hint="Enter service needed..." />
            --> 



        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/sTime"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:entries="@array/entries3"
            android:prompt="@string/prompt3" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/sNeeded"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:entries="@array/entries4"
            android:prompt="@string/prompt4" />



        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/eComments"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:imeActionLabel="Next"
            android:hint="Enter Comments Here..."
            android:inputType="textMultiLine" />
    </LinearLayout>
  </ScrollView> 




<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="40"
    android:orientation="vertical" >        

     <Button
    android:id="@+id/bSentEmail"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="Submit"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:onClick="handleClick"
    />

</LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Date Class:

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.method.KeyListener;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TextView.OnEditorActionListener;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ScheduleService extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
EditText /* serviceTime, serviceNeeded, vehicleYear, vehicleMake, */
        personsFirstName,
        personsLastName,
        personsEmail,
        personsPhone,
        comments,
        vehicleModel;
Spinner serviceTime, serviceNeeded, vehicleYear, vehicleMake;
TextView serviceDate;
String fname, lname, phoneNumber, vehicleYears, vehicleModeltrim,
        vehicleManu, serviceAppointment, serviceAppointmentTime,
        serviceTypeNeeded, extraComments, emailAdd, emailaddress, message;
Button sendEmail, PickDate ;
private TextView mDateDisplay;
 private Button mPickDate;
 private int mYear;
 private int mMonth;
 private int mDay;


 static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.service);
    initialize();

    PickDate.setOnClickListener(this);


}

public void onClick(){
     //
        mDateDisplay = (TextView)  findViewById(R.id.dateDisplay);
        mPickDate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pickDate);

        // add a click listener to the button
        mPickDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
            }
        });

        // get the current date
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // display the current date
        updateDisplay();
    }
    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
        case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
            return new DatePickerDialog(this,
                        mDateSetListener,
                        mYear, mMonth, mDay);
        }
        return null;
    }

    // updates the date we display in the TextView
    private void updateDisplay() {
        mDateDisplay.setText(
            new StringBuilder()
                    // Month is 0 based so add 1
                    .append(mMonth + 1).append("-")
                    .append(mDay).append("-")
                    .append(mYear).append(" "));
    }
    // the callback received when the user "sets" the date in the dialog
    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener =
            new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                      int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                    mYear = year;
                    mMonth = monthOfYear;
                    mDay = dayOfMonth;
                    updateDisplay();
                }
    };



// Use the following commented fields for future Spinner properties
private void initialize() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    personsFirstName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.firstName);
    personsLastName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.lastName);
    personsEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Email);
    personsPhone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.PhoneNumber);
    vehicleYear = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sYear);
    vehicleMake = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sMake);
    // vehicleYear = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tYear);
    // vehicleMake = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tMake);
    vehicleModel = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Model);
    serviceDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dateDisplay);
    serviceTime = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sTime);
    serviceNeeded = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sNeeded);
    // serviceTime = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tTime);
    // serviceNeeded = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tNeeded);
    comments = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eComments);
    sendEmail = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSentEmail);
    PickDate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pickDate);

}

public void handleClick(View v) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    conversion();
    String emailaddress[] = { "some@email.com" };
    String message = "Please Review the following:" + '\n' + " " + '\n'
            + "First Name: " + fname + '\n' + "Last Name: " + lname + '\n'
            + "Email :" + emailAdd + '\n' + "Phone Number: " + phoneNumber
            + '\n' + "Vechile Year: " + vehicleYears + '\n'
            + "Vehicle Make: " + vehicleManu + '\n' + "Vehicle Model: "
            + vehicleModeltrim + '\n' + "Requested Service Date: "
            + serviceAppointment + '\n' + "Requested Service Time: "
            + serviceAppointmentTime + '\n' + "Service Needed: "
            + serviceTypeNeeded + '\n' + "Comments: " + extraComments;

    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    emailIntent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.dir/email");
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,
            new String[] { "some@email.com" });
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, emailaddress);
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,
            "Mobile App: Schedule Service Request");
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent,
            "Please select Email Client"));

}

private void conversion() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    fname = personsFirstName.getText().toString();
    lname = personsLastName.getText().toString();
    emailAdd = personsEmail.getText().toString();
    phoneNumber = personsPhone.getText().toString();

    // vehicleYears = vehicleYear.getText().toString();// Text field
    // substitute for spinner adapter
    // vehicleManu = vehicleMake.getText().toString(); // Text field
    // substitute for spinner adapter
    vehicleYears = (String) vehicleYear.getSelectedItem().toString();
    vehicleManu = (String) vehicleMake.getSelectedItem().toString();
    vehicleModeltrim = vehicleModel.getText().toString();
    serviceAppointment = serviceDate.getText().toString();
    // serviceAppointmentTime = serviceTime.getText().toString();
    // serviceTypeNeeded = serviceNeeded.getText().toString();

    serviceAppointmentTime = (String) serviceTime.getSelectedItem()
            .toString();
    serviceTypeNeeded = (String) serviceNeeded.getSelectedItem().toString();
    extraComments = comments.getText().toString();
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    finish();

}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    {

    }

}
```

}

Comment: You're going to want to include a stacktrace here.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling

```
mPickDate.setOnClickListener(this);
```

before

```
mPickDate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pickDate);
```

which would cause a NullPointerException, and therefore a crash. Set the listener after you initilize the Button variable

Comment: I will edit the code. I was still having issues, so I consolidated the classes together. Currently, the text view (where the date should be displayed) reads false; however if you click the button, it seems to refresh the page and then displays the date.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing three separate types of `onClick` callback.

- In the XML, you are specifying by name the function that will be called in the `Activity` class.  If I were using this method, I would direct clicks to a function other than `onClick()`.
- In the `Date` activity, you are implementing `OnClickListener` and then sending button clicks to the containing activity.  This would call the `onClick()` method at the bottom of the class.  Later, you specify the `OnClickListener` to be a function defined in-line.  I would not do this latter.
- In the `ScheduleService` activity, you are implementing `OnClickListener` and then sending button clicks to the containing activity.  Later, you implement `onClick()`.  This is typical.

For more information about handling `onClick()`, see "Easier click listeners" in this article: http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/ui-1.6.html